# Как подставить значение в id элемента при нажатии?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Есть блок с id=478, который выводит картинку на экран, и 5 ссылок(скрин), при нажатии на которые нужно чтобы их значение подставлялось в значение id div-элемента. Как это реализовать?

```
 <div id="478"  class="popup">
   <a href="#" class="popup-area"></a>
    <div class="popup-body">
        <div class="popup-content">
            <a href="#" class="popup-close">X</a>
            <div class="popup-image"><img height="100%" width="100%" src="screenshot/1body4floor/478.jpg" alt=""></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Есть блок с id=478, который выводит картинку на экран, и 5 ссылок(скрин)

при этом адрес на скрине... index2.php#**479**

и адреса ссылкок как я понимаю - #478 #479 #480 #481 #482

короче css target tabs.

> при нажатии на которые нужно чтобы их значение подставлялось в значение id div-элемента

т.е. вам нужна динамическая смена содержимого текущего блока вместо перехода к другому блоку. типа пагинация верно?

```css
br{display:none;}
#b1:target ~ #x:after{content:'b1';}
#b2:target ~ #x:after{content:'b2';}
#b3:target ~ #x:after{content:'b3';}
#b4:target ~ #x:after{content:'b4';}
```

```html
<br id='b1'>
<br id='b2'>
<br id='b3'>
<br id='b4'>

<div id='x'>abc </div>

<a href='#b1'>b1</a>
<a href='#b2'>b2</a>
<a href='#b3'>b3</a>
<a href='#b4'>b4</a>
```

если не пагинация а банальный слайдер, то... для таких целей кмк `input[type=radio]:checked` больше подходит. ну правда, зачем гадить в uri и историю по пустякам.

Answer (score 0):

с учетом того, что вы забыли добавить ссылки в верстку, предположим, что они находятся внутри этого дива, и имеют вид `<a href="#" data-id="xxx" class="x-link">xxx</a>`, то код будте примерно таким%

```
$(".x-link").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.popup').attr('id', $(this).data('id'));
});
```

если на момент инициализации скрипта данные ссылки в документе отсутствуют, то читать статьи про привязку динамических объектов DOM через `.on(...)`

Comment: Человек, который не может написать банальный клик вряд ли будет что-то читать `про привязку динамических объектов DOM через [что угодно]`))